# Sensitive, cranky, irritable, touchy

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-difference, word-in-context

I get angry very easily by other people. I'm a very sensitive person.

How do I describe this kind of personality ?

Sensitive, cranky, irritable, touchy, mean. I got these words from the dictionary,so I'm not sure if these are really used in real life.

Are they informal/ formal?

Is there any better choice?

Answer (score 2):

**The informal ones:** Cranky, Mean

**The in-between ones:** Touchy, Sensitive

**The formal ones:** Irritable

---

It might be a bit weird to put **"mean"** in the informal section, but in all my time working in a professional or academic environment, another word is usually used in its place.

I've never heard anyone use **"cranky"** except for parents talking about their kids, or when it's someone from an older generation.

**"Sensitive"** is a decent word, but I put it in the "in-between" section because I use it either way. An HR representative in a company would say something, but I also might joke with my friends by saying "Someone's a bit sensitive today." It's probably the best word that you can use at any time in this context.

Personally, I don't use **"touchy"** and never really hear it in any situations.  It could still work, but it would be uncommon to hear.  I put this word in the "in-between" section because I honestly don't know where it would fall, because I *just don't hear it enough.*

I never use **"irritable"** in casual conversation with people, unless we're actively describing someone's personality.  For example, I (or someone else) might say "Jane is usually irritable in the winter", but never something like "Wow, you're being irritable today."

---

My personal recommendation would be to use **irritable** if you were going to describe yourself to someone, and **sensitive** for any other time.